# De wa or dewa, noob question

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-で

What does *dewa* mean here?

> ブラウンさん、日本語**では**、トイレはお手洗いと同じ意味ですよ

I haven't really studied it yet and thought it was kind of a negative used like *janai*, but here it means-

> Brown-san, in Japanese, toilet has the same meaning as bathroom.

Or is it using the *de* and *wa* particles separately or something? I think just using *wa* would have worked?

Answer (score 3):

It's the use of the particle で + particle は, as you suggest.

で in this case marks the mean/tool...

は is a particle that marks the topic of the sentence and that can be added to other particles like this (as a general rule, don't take this for granted 100% of the time):

- It absorbs が and を.

  > 私は学生だ。 私 is both the topic and the subject of the sentence.
  >
  > これは昨日買ったんだ。 これ is both the topic and the direct object of the sentence.
- It either absorbs or is added to  the particle に.

  > 庭(に)は犬がいる。
- It's added to other case particles.

  > 日本では箸で食べる。

Therefore:

> Brown-san, in Japanese, トイレ has the same meaning as お手洗い.

"In Japanese" being the topic, the hearer's attention is put on the rest of the sentence which is the new information.

Comment: Missed opportunity for 庭には二羽の鶏がいる.  .: *womp womp* :.

Comment: @istrasci: 庭{にわ}には二羽{にわ}に鰐{わに}はにやにや俄{にわ}かに噛{か}みつけた。 (^^)

Comment: But would the sentence in question still make sense if we omitted で?

Comment: @kuchitsu In that sentence, still makes sense but has a quite different meaning.

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly it would be different or recommend something I can read on the topic?

Comment: @broccoli forest could you explain what the difference would be? I feel the meaning would be "日本語、トイレ and お手洗い have the same meaning", but that doesn't really make sense : )

Comment: @kuchitsu & Alox It depends on context. 日本語は、トイレはお手洗いと同じ意味です sounds like "Japanese is (a language that) _toilet_ has..." or "But (unlike some languages,) in Japanese, _toilet_ has..." I think it only appears when you discuss languages, not when somebody used bad Japanese.